# How to check whether a permissions exists in a particular version of Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, android-permissions

I am trying to build an app, as a self project, to understand permissions in detail. There are certain permissions, such as 'Bluetooth Connect' that was introduced in Android version 12 (API 31). Now if I am building an app with multiple features, say some of the features were introduced in the first version of Android, but some of them were introduced in the last version, do I have a method to check whether said permission exists in Android? The idea is to remove or restrict those features which are using APIs not defined and still have the app run on all phones.

For example, In my tests, I have noticed the permission when checked, using the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` method, come back as 'Not granted' for permissions that are supposed to be undefined. Essentially, I want to know if there is a method of knowing whether the permissions are 'undefined'.

Additionally, I have seen some research papers go into the Android system logs and retrieve information. For example - [image: System log entry on API15] . This is from the paper: [Sleeping android: the danger of dormant permissions](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2516760.2516774)
I've tried to use ADB logcat to read the log files but not only is it very difficult, it doesn't say anything similar. Am I doing it wrong or was there an update which removed the information?
Even if I can see whether the permission exists or not via logs would be helpful.

Comment: `a method to check whether said permission exists in Android? ` All permissions are part of Android. Pretty unclear what you wanna know. You could have asked,: wich permissions are used in manifest file. Or which permissions are accepted by user.

Comment: @blackapps In a particular version of Android is what I meant. 
'Bluetooth Scan' was introduced in Android 12. Hence it wouldn't be available for Android 10, right? 
In this case I know the permission doesn't exist on 10. But how I check if permission xyz exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Lint is set up to check this for you at compile time. It will force you to check that the SDK version is high enough to check for whichever permission you’re trying to use. For instance, if your `minSdkVersion` is lower than the version in which a permission constant was introduced, it will be a compile error to use that constant without wrapping it in an if statement that makes sure the SDK version on the device is high enough for it to exist.

I’m not sure how you have defeated this mechanism except that maybe you have compiled the app with Lint disabled.

The paper you linked is absolutely ancient. Lint probably didn’t help you with this back then.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this initially. Thought Lint was an external tool.
I'm not sure how I disabled Lint tho. Huh.
Also, yes, the paper is old and there's no mention of Lint in it.